# I can't get my monitor to display pure black

Tags: windows-10, display, colors, calibration

I was concerned that my new monitor seemed to have rather extreme backlight bleed - things that were supposed to be black were showing up as charcoal gray. So I decided to do some tests, and I found something wrong, but it's not blacklight bleed.

In the attached photograph, the monitor is displaying a full-screen web page with a pure black #000000 background. The screen should be as dark as it can get. But I've enabled the monitor's brightness and contrast controls, and the overlay is clearly displaying a darker black than the supposedly pure black image on the screen.

I tried several black pages in several browsers, and I also tried picking a black color in an image editing application. I can't get anything darker than this dark grey, even though the overlay clearly indicates that the monitor is physically capable of displaying a darker black.

How can I get black to show up on this monitor as black? (I'm running Windows 10, and connected to an RTX 2070 SUPER with an HDMI cable.)

[image: photo of black overlay on "black" screen image.]

Comment: What video driver are you using and what are its settings?

Comment: Have you calibrated it, or at least set it to the manufacture's profile

Comment: Some monitors (especially the cheap) have often lighter edges because the light distributing foil is not perfectly mounted. Your monitor photo looks like especially the edges show more a dark gray than black so it could be this issue.

Comment: @squillman the graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super. The driver is NVIDIA's driver version 31.0.15.1694, dated 7/21/2022.

Comment: @Robert The manufacturer's color management profile is active, it's called "Dell S2721S Color Profile,D6500". The Windows display calibration only sets the gamma, so it's not relevant. (After setting the gamma, it says to use the buttons on the monitor to adjust the brightness and contrast. These buttons don't affect the minimum displayed black level.)

Comment: @Josh I wasn't talking about color profiles, I was talking about a minor "hardware defect" that cheap display have but as they are cheap they are sold even without that defect.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was meant for @Tetsujin. Dell isn't the sort of company I would expect to deliberately sell monitors with hardware defects, they have a reputation to uphold. Also, this is an issue over the whole screen - although the corners look slightly brighter, you can see that the whole screen is much brighter than the overlay.